# iPhone SDK: NSURL string errors/ % sign confrontation

Tags: iphone, ios, url, uiwebview

in my piece of coding to get a url to reach a website, I encounter a warning. The app still loads but the url does not load the web view. This is my code:

```
   NSString *strWebsiteUlr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1359826314&rver=6.1.6195.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Flogin.secure.co1.msn.com%2Fwlsignin.aspx%3Fru%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strWebsiteUlr];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[eMail loadRequest:requestObj];
```

With this code, I receive a warning saying: More % conversions than data arguments. What I'm guessing it's saying is that I have percentage signs that don't correspond ot an argument; however, this is part of the url and when I try to load this the webview stays blank. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `stringWithFormat:` in this case because you aren't trying to insert any values in the string.  Change your code to the following:

```
NSString *strWebsiteUlr = @"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1359826314&rver=6.1.6195.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Flogin.secure.co1.msn.com%2Fwlsignin.aspx%3Fru%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strWebsiteUlr];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[eMail loadRequest:requestObj];
```

You could also skip the `strWebsiteUlr` variable entirely and just do:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1359826314&rver=6.1.6195.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Flogin.secure.co1.msn.com%2Fwlsignin.aspx%3Fru%3Dhttp%253a%252f%252"];
```

If you did want to insert values in the string using `stringWithFormat:` you can escape the percent signs with another percent, e.g. `%%`.